# Can I define a type synonym inside the "let" block?

Tags: haskell, types, syntax

I want to get something like this. It's possible?

```hs
something :: String
something = 
  let
    type FirstName = String
    type LastName = String
    
    fullName :: FirstName -> LastName -> String
    fullName = a ++ " " ++ b
  in
    fullName "Haskell" "Curry"
```

I've been trying to find language extensions that do this, but to no avail.

Comment: Just write it top-level

Comment: Yes, but it was interesting to find out if it is possible to define a type **in the local** scope, and **not in the global** one.

Comment: Yes it is interesting, such a feature could be implemented and would mostly be useful for a synonym that captures variables in scope. It is usually bad style to have a function so large that it requires declaring names that are only used within that function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direct answer is no, type definitions are possible only on module level.

Something similar is possible:

```hs
let
  fullName ::
    (firstName ~ String, lastName ~ String) =>
    firstName -> lastName -> String
  fullName a b = a ++ " " ++ b
in
  _
```

Comment: What is `~`, how does it differ from `::`?

Comment: > _A type context can include equality constraints of the form t1 ~ t2, which denote that the types t1 and t2 need to be the same._

I get it from [The Glorious GHC System User's Guide, Version 7.4.1](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/equality-constraints.html)